# Update date inside mongoose schema every time

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm trying to update the `lastMessageAt` every time the `[messageSchema]` is updated.

It doesn't work this way. I The only date that is generated when the messageSchema is filled with it's very first object.

How do i solve this?

Thanks in advance!

```
const chatSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  userName1: String,
  userName2: String,
  messages: [messageSchema],
  lastMessageAt: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use mongooses post middleware.

```
chatSchema.post('save', function(next) {
  if (this.isModified('messages')) {
    this.lastMessageAt = Date.now();
  }
  next();
});
```

Comment: thanks for your help, but i get a bad request when doing this :-(

Comment: i just found out that mongoose has now built in timestamps. thank you  man!! :-)

Answer (score 0):

found out that mongoose now has built in timestamps and they are used like this:

```
const chatSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    userName1: String,
    userName2: String,
    messages: [messageSchema]
  },
  { timestamps: true }
);
```